# Cron daemon reporting "unknown user 'tomcat6'" every day since I removed tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, cron, logrotate

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. Since I removed tomcat via `aptitude purge` the other day, I keep getting the following error from Cron daily:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: tomcat6:7 unknown user 'tomcat6'
error: found error in /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out , skipping
```

I want to get rid of this error message, but I have absolutely no idea where to start. I don't even really understand what the point of the error message is.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the `logrotate` software (that, as the name says, "rotate" logs) complaining about a non-existent user configured to rotate your tomcat logs.

Try searching the `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory for something like "tomcat" or "tomcat6" and remove the file if you find it, it's useless now that tomcat is not installed anymore.